# How to get CurrentLocation from GPS FirstTime quickly?

Tags: android

Iam using

```
locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
String bestProvider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(bestProvider, 0, 0, this);
location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(bestProvider);
```

but first time it is not giving location object.Always giving me null.I read in developer.android.com ,

> "Cached Location is dismissed if it is
>   too old"

But second time it is giving location updates.How to solve my problem.

Regards,
Android Developer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are few options... if `getLastKnownLocation()` is null because it's to old you only can wait to get a newer position fix.

However if you don't need a very accurate location you can use the networkProvider which is faster.

Answer (score 0):

mLocManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        mLocManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
        mLocManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
        CellLocation.requestLocationUpdate();

Call these all statement together..
and there is no way to simply seek device LAT and LONG  statically ..
You have to wait for update..... Use any progress bar or do any other waiting stuff...

In the onLocationChanged method .. recieve the location object and save its reference to any of your class...